# Actual Destination IP instead of Proxy's IP in traffic capture

Tags: networking, proxy, sniffing

I want to capture the network traffic of my host through wireshark and need to get the source and destination ip addresses from the packets. The problem I am facing is that I am behind Proxy Server and I get the IP of proxy as the destination IPs. However, I want to get the IP address of the actual server that is accessed through my host.

Is it possible that I can get the actual destination IPs instead of Proxy's IP.

Comment: If it's HTTP traffic, the proxy might put the original client IP in an HTTP request header. Other than that, it's not possible.

Comment: ok is there any way to capture the traffic over proxy server to include both actual source and destination IP Addresses?? May be some kind of configuration in the Server

Comment: You need to do the capture on the proxy server itself. Or if the outside interface of the proxy is connected to a switch, you can put the sniffer on a monitoring port of the switch so it will see all the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. Assuming you want to know about getting information about the destination host with which the packets are exchanged via the proxy server, here is the explanation.

The HTTP client normally uses the hostname part of the URL to do a DNS lookup to connect to the requested host. Then, it sends an HTTP GET request for the rest of the URL. The hostname is also included in that request. Now, if you are behind a proxy server, the HTTP GET requests are first sent to this proxy server from where they are forwarded to the destination host. Any responses received take the same reverse path.

Now to capture and filter packets of that host, type

```
http.host == 'www.example.com'
```

in the display filter box. Then, in the field titled "Info" you could figure out the packets that belong to [example.com](http://example.com). You can get the details of this packet by double-clicking on it. Note that you would not see the IP address of the host in the destination address field, rather it would represent the proxy server you are using and its GeoLocation.

So what you need to look at is the TCP connection and the host name part of the GET requests. These requests are send forward, and the responses come back the same way. So your endpoint tracking has raised from the network level to the session level.

If you wish to determine the ip address of a host, you can simply use online tools such as [spfld](http://www.spfld.com/ping.html) or [iplocation](https://www.iplocation.net/), provided you know its domain name.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOgdl.png), I have shown an example of packets captured from the host example.com. Note that the source address value shown in the image (10.3.2.65) is my hostel room IP while the destination address value (202.141.80.24) shown is the proxy server of my institute. I have filtered all the HTTP packets exchanged with the host example.com

But if you want to find the IP address of the host directly through Wireshark, then, as mentioned in the comments, its not possible as of now.